# Unity: what and when to register

Tags: asp.net, unity-container

My current implementation of some ASP.NET web application registers all repository classes and some helper service classes in my wrapper around unity container:

```
public class MyUnityContainer : UnityContainer
{
    public MyUnityContainer ()
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        _context = new MyDataClassesDataContext(strConnectionString);

        this
            .RegisterInstance(typeof(CMCoreDataClassesDataContext), _context, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
            ;

        //  Register Repository classes
        this
            .RegisterType<IBlockedRegistrationRepository, BlockedRegistrationRepository>()
            .RegisterType<ICmOptionRepository, CmOptionRepository>()
            .RegisterType<ICommandExecutionLogRepository, CommandExecutionLogRepository>()
        ...
    }

    public static T GetContainer<T>(IDictionary items) where T : class, IUnityContainer, new()
    {
        T container;
        lock (Lock)
        {
            if (items.Contains(UnityKey) == false)
            {
                container = new T();
                items.Add(UnityKey, container);
            }
            else
            {
                container = items[UnityKey] as T;
            }
        }

        return container;
    }
```

Here is an example how container is instantiated (I create a new instance of the container per each request, but only one instance per request):

```
        using (IUnityContainer container = MyUnityContainer.GetContainer<McaUnityContainer>(HttpContext.Current.Items))
        { ... }
```

Everything is working fine, but what one thing is confusing me a lot: now I have almost 50 classes been registered each time when container is created. Not all classes are actually used for each request...

Is not it a performance overhead to ALWAYS register everything in container?
Probably I shouldn't instantiate a new container instance for each request (and use something like containers pool)?

What is a best practice recommendations for this case?

Thanks a lot.

Any thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

In our internal framework, we have a static instance of the Unity container that hangs off the Global.asax file, and gets instantiated (and filled with registrations) on Application Start.

On each request, we use Container.CreateChildContainer() to get a request-specific container that gets a very few request-specific registrations (even fewer if you use Unity 2.0 with HierarchicalLifetimeManager). The request-specific container is what gets used during the request.

Edited to add: Not to say this is necessarily a best practice. It certainly avoids any registration overhead though, except for app startup where I have bigger fish to fry from an overhead perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I register everything needed by the web application in Application_Start. I have a `RequestLifetimeManager` like [this](http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=38588) and a `SessionLifeTimeManager`, to make request-specific and session-specific dependencies to be created only when needed: didn't yet see performance or memory issues related to this approach. Our policy is to create a child container when the context is different, for instance in web services or background tasks.